# ABPersonViewController causes UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency on iPad when choosing a photo

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using an ABPersonViewController in a UINavigationController to display and edit contact information. This has worked up until now using the latest xcode version (4.5.2 currently) and iOS6. If the user selects the Edit button on the ABPersonViewController the view goes into edit mode (as expected) but now if they choose Photo (to add or change an existing photo) then "Choose Photo" the application crashes with the following exception?...

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View ; }; layer = > is associated with <_UIActionSheetHostingController: 0x4da1190>. Clear this association before associating this view with <_UIActionSheetHostingController: 0x5f38830>.'*****

It seems to be specific for iPad - I imagine it has something to do with how the iPad treats action sheets as popovers unless displayed within a popover. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried presenting the ABUnknownPersonViewController both by pushing to a navigation controller and displaying in new navigation controller modally, but same problem with both solutions.

Comment: I now use a popover to edit contacts which works fine.

Comment: when i put it in a popover i don't get a keyboard when enabling the textfields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the new orientation methods of UIViewController:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

It seems the choose-photo VC does not implement them, so make sure that your root VC does implement them even when its top VC doesn't.

In code:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask topControllerOrientationMask = [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    return topControllerOrientationMask ? topControllerOrientationMask : UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    UIInterfaceOrientation topControllerOrientation = [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    return topControllerOrientation ? topControllerOrientation : UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
@end
```